# Corollary 5.3.4 in Szamuely, Galois group and fundamental groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

There is a specific point in the proof of Corollary 5.3.4 in Szamuely, Galois group and fundamental groups that I can't seem to fully understand .

Specifically the statement is

Corollary 5.3.4.

If $:⟶$ is a connected finite etale cover, the nontrivial elements of $Aut(|)$ act without fixed points on each geometric fibre. Hence $Aut(|)$ is finite .

The proof of this corollary seems to be an immediate consequence of the following :

Corollary 5.3.3.

If $⟶$ is a connected -scheme and $_1,_2:⟶$ are two -morphisms to a finite étale -scheme  with $_1∘=_2∘$ for some geometric point $:Spec(Ω)⟶$, then $_1=_2$.

From this statement it is clear that any geometric point of $X$ can't be fixed by any element of $Aut(|)$ but I still wonder how this implies that the action of $Aut(|)$ on $X×_SSpec(Ω)$ can't fix any points of the fibre where $:Spec(Ω)⟶S$ a geometric point .

There was another mathstackexchange question posted regarding that proof:

[enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792082/action-of-the-group-of-automorphisms-of-a-connected-finite-%C3%A9tale-cover-corollar?rq=1)

but it doesn't seem to answer my question .

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: The points of $X\times_S{\rm Spec}(\Omega)$ are in one-to-one correspondence with liftings of $z$ to $X$. These liftings cannot be fixed by what you write. So what is the difficulty?